# Call to FontFamily::GenericMonospace fails

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am trying to get a font for writing text on a bitmap, but the call for getting a fontfamily fails with a writing access violation.
This is my code:

```
RectF pos(bih.biWidth / 2, bih.biHeight / 2, bih.biWidth * 0.65, bih.biHeight * 0.5);
SolidBrush brush(Color::Black);
Font font(FontFamily::GenericMonospace(), 22);
hr = g.DrawString(this->introText, 11, &font, pos, NULL, &brush);
```

This is where the exception is triggered:

```
FontFamily::GenericMonospace()
{
    if (GenericMonospaceFontFamily != NULL)
    {
        return GenericMonospaceFontFamily;
    }

    GenericMonospaceFontFamily =
        (FontFamily*) GenericMonospaceFontFamilyBuffer;

    GenericMonospaceFontFamily->lastResult =
        DllExports::GdipGetGenericFontFamilyMonospace(
            &(GenericMonospaceFontFamily->nativeFamily)
        ); //this is the next step after the exception (according to vs)

    return GenericMonospaceFontFamily;
}
```

I have tried using another FontFamily, which gives the same result.
I have also tried using a specific font by using it's name as a string to the Font Constructor, but it couldn't find the font this way.

Comment: Access violation exceptions are almost always caused by heap corruption.  The code that triggers the exception is never the cause of the corruption, that was done by *some* code that ran earlier.

Comment: some code that ran earlier in the same function, the same thread or the whole application?

Comment: I put this line of code that triggers the exception at first possible position and this stil triggers the exception. So there is no code that ran before it.

Comment: That sounds fishy.  You must initialize GDI+ before you use any of its functions.  Calling GdiplusStartup() is a hard requirement.